# Use Math.random() to display percentage number in Java

Tags: java, random, percentage

Currently coding simple program. I want to display percentage of each visit to the store in 52 weeks. For example, "In 52 weeks store number 1 was inspected 20%".
Here is the code so far.

```
public class StoreSelection {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for( int i=1; i<=52;i++){
        int randomSelection = 1+(int)(Math.random()*4);
        System.out.println(i+" week"+" Store number "+randomSelection+"   will be inspected");
    }
    // here should be stated "In 52 weeks store number 1 was visited (number of percentage)
    // and then below "In 52 weeks store number 2 was visited (number of percentage)  
    //and same for number 3 and 4.
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't very clear. How many stores can be selected? Do you want to store that result and use it later? Is that the goal of this program?

Comment: 4 stores should be visited. Each week a store is randomly selected. The output is "1 week Store number 2 will be inspected" which is loop for 52 times. After its done percentage of each store in 52 weeks should be displayed. That is the end of the program. I wont use stored result later.

Comment: Hey, I posted an answer. Let me know if you need something else done to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an int array to store the number of selections each store received.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] storeVisits = new int[4];
  for (int i = 1; i <= 52; i++) {
    int randomSelection = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    storeVisits[randomSelection - 1]++; // randomSelection -1 is used because arrays start at 0
    System.out.println(i + " week" + " Store number " + randomSelection + "   will be inspected");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < storeVisits.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("In 52 weeks store number " + (i + 1) + " was visited "
        + ((storeVisits[i] * 100) / 52) + "%");
  }
}
```

which outputs (will change each time):

```
1 week Store number 4   will be inspected
2 week Store number 3   will be inspected
3 week Store number 3   will be inspected
4 week Store number 2   will be inspected
5 week Store number 3   will be inspected
6 week Store number 3   will be inspected
7 week Store number 3   will be inspected
8 week Store number 2   will be inspected
9 week Store number 2   will be inspected
10 week Store number 1   will be inspected
11 week Store number 3   will be inspected
12 week Store number 4   will be inspected
13 week Store number 4   will be inspected
14 week Store number 4   will be inspected
15 week Store number 1   will be inspected
16 week Store number 2   will be inspected
17 week Store number 3   will be inspected
18 week Store number 4   will be inspected
19 week Store number 4   will be inspected
20 week Store number 3   will be inspected
21 week Store number 4   will be inspected
22 week Store number 1   will be inspected
23 week Store number 2   will be inspected
24 week Store number 1   will be inspected
25 week Store number 4   will be inspected
26 week Store number 4   will be inspected
27 week Store number 2   will be inspected
28 week Store number 2   will be inspected
29 week Store number 2   will be inspected
30 week Store number 1   will be inspected
31 week Store number 1   will be inspected
32 week Store number 4   will be inspected
33 week Store number 4   will be inspected
34 week Store number 4   will be inspected
35 week Store number 1   will be inspected
36 week Store number 3   will be inspected
37 week Store number 1   will be inspected
38 week Store number 2   will be inspected
39 week Store number 1   will be inspected
40 week Store number 4   will be inspected
41 week Store number 1   will be inspected
42 week Store number 4   will be inspected
43 week Store number 1   will be inspected
44 week Store number 2   will be inspected
45 week Store number 1   will be inspected
46 week Store number 1   will be inspected
47 week Store number 1   will be inspected
48 week Store number 3   will be inspected
49 week Store number 4   will be inspected
50 week Store number 4   will be inspected
51 week Store number 4   will be inspected
52 week Store number 4   will be inspected
In 52 weeks store number 1 was visited 26%
In 52 weeks store number 2 was visited 19%
In 52 weeks store number 3 was visited 19%
In 52 weeks store number 4 was visited 34%
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. I see that using array is the best solution. Thinking about it and trying to exclude array from the program, do you think it is possible to do other way without using array?

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cat. You could use a hashmap<int storeNum, int visitCount> or write a class for the store object and update visits as needed. I don't mind implementing one of these for you if need be, but you should have a specific reason for not using the implementation there.

Comment: @Ivanko you could use four variables, int storeOne, int storeTwo, int storeThree, int storeFour and then add to each depending on the result from random.

Comment: Don't have any specific reason for excluding array, was just trying to think of other ways which you already mentioned. I will experiment the code with array first. You've been very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

public class StoreSelection {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int weeks = 52;
    int storeCount = 4;
    int[] stores = new int[storeCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < weeks; i++) {
        int randomSelection = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * storeCount);
        System.out.println((i+1) + " week: " + " Store number " + randomSelection
                + "   will be inspected");
        stores[randomSelection-1]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < storeCount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Store " + (i+1) + " was visited "
                + (stores[i] / 52.0 * 100.0) + "% times");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Zaki, using array is great, I am still thinking if its possible to do it other way without an array.

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: No reason really. I was just thinking to compute percentage of visits without using arrays and second loop, but will experiment with arrays more.

Comment: You can change the code creating four variables each holding number of visits for each store.

Comment: Right. As lacraig2 mentioned that is the other way. i will try that first and then using array. Thank you for your help.